# Input resistance of an op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, resistance, input-impedance

I need to find the input resistance of this circuit. There are two parts of this exercise:

- The first one is to find the input resistance of the circuit without the capacitor.
- The second is to the find the input resistance of the circuit with the capacitor ( C = 1nF.)

It is not mentioned if the op-amp is ideal or not.

I have seen a lot of topics related to this subject but I haven't figured it out yet. Do I need to find the equivalent resistance of the circuit? Do I have to take into account the interior components of the op-amp?

[image]

Comment: Well, if the op-amp is perfect, no current is absorbed from the (+) pin so the resistance seen from \$v_s\$ is quite straightforward, no? If the (+) input now offers a resistance across \$R_2\$, it does not really complicate the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether C is in place or not has no effect on the characteristics of the non-inverting input. Considering that the system consisting of \$v_S\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ is effectively disconnected from anything else in the circuit (by the opamp's high input resistance), you can ignore everything else.

I suppose that this particular op-amp *could* have terribly low input impedance, or significant input bias current, or \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are so large that its input impedance becomes significant. Then \$C\$ might feature in your calculations, but one of the benefits of op-amps, to remove such nuisance dependencies between inputs and everything else, is defeated anyway.

So, without further context, I don't think your question requires anything more than a simple addition.

Answer (score 2):

In the "bad" case you use an "LM741", you should have this ... (red curve is C=0).
In other cases, you should see "only" 6k7 impedance.

[image]

> Do I need to find the equivalent resistance of the circuit?
> Do I have to take into account the interior components of the op-amp?

No